# Finding the inverse of the arc length equation of a parabola

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need help in reversing the equation of the arc length of a parabola.

$$y = \frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{1+4\cdot x^2} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \ln(2\cdot x + \sqrt{1+4\cdot x^2})$$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Do you have tried anything?
Please use MathJax for a better reading: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is this really your problem? Or is it just a step within the solution of another problem?

Comment: yes. I need to find x knowing y

Comment: What @JoséCarlosSantos is hinting at is that if you would provide context, someone might be able to suggest a line of attack that doesn't lead down this cul-de-sac.  You're not going to get an expression for $x$ in any kind of usable form, but there might be some other way to solve your problem that avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seem to somewhat misunderstood. Let me express it this way: Find the function $y(x)$ whose arc length is given by

$$s=\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}~dx=\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{1+4\cdot x^2} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \ln(2\cdot x + \sqrt{1+4\cdot x^2})$$

Differentiating both sides we get

$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}=\sqrt{4x^2+1}\\
1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2=4x^2+1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\\
\fbox{$y=\pm x^2+C$}
$$

I have verified this solution numerically.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not answer the question and is a replacement of the original question by another one: in the notation of the OP, y is the arc length of the parabole (that is what Cye Waldman denoted by s).

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not have an analytical solution. You can invert this equation numerically with numerical solver.

Alternatively, you can transform this problem into a differential equation problem, that can be solved numerically too:

We have by definition of the arc length 
$$y = \int \sqrt{ 1 + f'(x)^2} dx. $$
Here $$f(x) = x^2$$  So 
$$dy =\sqrt{ 1 + f'(x)^2} dx = \sqrt{ 1 + (2x)^2} dx $$
or $$ {dx\over dy}  = {1\over \sqrt{ 1 + 4x^2}}.$$
This is an explicit differential equation in x (as a function of y), whose 
solution is precisely the inverse function demanded by the OP. It can be solved numerically.